# i dont know how to fix my error -- node.js and npm

Tags: node.js

ok, so I keep getting this error 'DOCKER_REPO' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I don't know how to fix it I'm pretty new to coding so if someone could help me out with this it would be very much appreciated I can leave a link to my debug log if needed

Comment: Hi, could you provide some further explanation or code?

Comment: what exactly are u asking for like what code are u asking for if ur asking for the log file I can send that edit: im using the npm run build command before I get the error

Comment: Hello, what do you want to do? What is the exact error message you got? What is the command you run?

Comment: here is the log file and the command I ran was 'npm run build' and the log is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rlhi5yoa36sgq4i/log%20file.txt?dl=0

Comment: Did U got docker installed ?? Do U got DOCKER_REPO  variable set in your machine ???

Comment: I do have docker installed but how do I do the variable

Comment: how do I set the docker _repo variable can someone explain please